# In Revelation 4:5, are the seven spirits before the throne of God the seven archangels in 1 Enoch 20:1-8?

Tags: revelation, angels, spirits, 1-enoch, divine-counsel

Revelation 4:5

> From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings and peals of thunder, and before the throne were burning seven torches of fire, which are the seven spirits of God.

Enoch lists the names of seven archangels (spirits?) and even details their functions:

1 Enoch 20:1–8

> And these are the names of the holy angels who watch. **Uriel**, one of the holy angels, who is over the world and over Tartarus. **Raphael**,  one of the holy angels, who is over the spirits of men. **Raguel**, one  of the holy angels who takes vengeance on the world of the luminaries.  **Michael**, one of the holy angels, to wit, he that is set over the best part of mankind and over chaos. **Saraqael**, one of the holy angels, who is set over the spirits, who sin in the spirit. **Gabriel**, one of the holy angels, who is over Paradise and the serpents and the Cherubim. **Remiel**, one of the holy angels, whom God set over those who rise.

From these verses, here are the names of the seven spirits of God and their jurisdictions:

1. Uriel—over the world and Tartarus
2. Raphael—over the spirits of men
3. Raguel—takes vengeance on the world of the luminaries
4. Michael—set over the best part of mankind and over chaos
5. Saraqael—set over the spirits who sin in the spirit
6. Gabriel—over Paradise and the serpents and the cherubim
7. Remiel—set over those who rise

Are these seven archangels the seven spirits before the throne and the seven eyes of God?

Comment: @Dottard - If you think not, then what are the Seven Spirits at God's throne?

Comment: This question has already been asked - see link above.

Comment: @Dottard I just checked that post, but nothing is said about the archangels.

Comment: The number "seven" is so frequently associated with God and matters relating to God that the coincidence of number is hardly enough to establush identity.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Dottard - what about Michael?  Both Gabriel and Michael are named in the Bible.

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel - actually, Gabriel is never called an archangel.  Only Michael is ever called an archangel in Jude 9 and Dan 10:13, 12:1.  These are possibly allusions to Ex 23:20-21.

Comment: @Dottard of course, all I'm saying is both Gabriel and Michael are angels mentioned in the Bible

Comment: @Dottard Doesn't Daniel 10:13 say, "one of the chief princes", plural? "Chief princes" would be "arch-angel" in English? Does this imply that there is more than one arch-angel?

Comment: @menorahman - I would not confuse no conflate arch-angel with chief prince.  The Bible only records a single archangel which is Michael.

Comment: For what it's worth, besides taking note of the "duplicate" question, you might want to check out my Q. linked here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81295/in-rev-45-we-are-told-that-the-7-lamps-of-fire-burning-before-gods-throne ... plus all the comments I gave under each and every answer, in which I make no reference at all to the book of Enoch, it being, at least IMO, of little to no relevance.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because it is not a duplicate... This question asks specifically  about the relation of the 7 spirits of God to seven archangels of Enoch. The book of Enoch is not mentioned in the supposedly duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify one of the OP's questions here is a relevant passage:

Revelation 5:6

> Then I saw standing in the middle of the throne and of the four living
> creatures, and in the middle of the elders, a Lamb that appeared to
> have been killed. He had seven horns and seven eyes, which are the
> seven spirits of God sent out into all the earth.

Scholars have noticed a good deal of similarity between the Revelation by the Book of Enoch. Whether this represents literary influence or similar spiritual experiences by the two writers is a matter of theological opinion. The parallels are quite striking and some do deal with angels, as the OP suggest. Some of the more clear-cut examples include:

- 1 Enoch 9:10 / Rev. 6:9 - The righteous dead call out to God for vindication and judgment.
- 1 Enoch 10:4 / Rev. 20:1 - The devil (Azazel in Enoch, Satan in Rev.) is bound by an angel (named Raphael in Enoch) and thrown into the abyss or fire.
- 1 Enoch 14:20 / Rev. 5:11 - Angels surrounding God's throne are said to number "ten thousand times ten thousand."
- 1 Enoch 20:2 / Rev. 1:20  - Seven guardian angels are named in Enoch; "The seven stars are the angels of the seven churches" in Revelation.

[The list goes on an on.](https://intertextual.bible/book/1-enoch/revelation)

There are no references to "seven eyes" in the Book of Enoch, but it does indeed speak of seven angelic "watchers." Since the seven eyes of Revelation are sent out to the whole earth, they could be related to the seven spirits of Enoch, whose function is to "watch." In terms of biblical literature, the "seven eyes" seem to be related to a passage in the Book of Zechariah implying God's omniscience:

Zechariah 4:10

> These are the eyes of the Lord, which constantly range across the
> whole earth.

**Conclusion:** Both Enoch and Revelation use symbols such as torches, candle flames, fires and stars to symbolize angels. There are angelic "watchers" in Enoch and (watchful) guardian angels of the churches in Revelation, as well as seven "eyes" of God in Rev. 5. Since the eyes are "sent out" they too serve the function of watchfulness, while the flashings and torches of the seven spirits represent illumination, which is essential to sight. It is therefore possible that Enoch's vision of seven major angels who "watch" is related to Revelation's vision of seven "spirits" associated with God's throne and the "eyes" of God that watch over the earth.

Comment: if the downvote resulted from my use of the word "influence" on Revelation by Enoch, I changed the opening section to note that the similarities between the two books may also have resulted from the two writers having similar spiritual experiences rather than literary influence.  I do wish downvoters would specify... it helps us all to learn and improve.